# How can i modify the context menu of a CEdit control?

Tags: windows-7, mfc, cedit

Before Windows 7 the solution was easy. Just add your own menu and write your own "Undo,Redo,Cut,Copy,Paste,Delete,Select All" menu items. But now this is not possible anymore because the menu has became really complex with the unicode and input message stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subclass the edit control then use a hook, following is an example code:

First is to subclass the edit control, usually in the `WndProc`:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HANDLE m_editControl; /* Supposing it is created */
        SetWindowSubclass(m_editControl, EditSubclassProc, 0, NULL);
    }
    break;
    default:
        /* default message handling */
    }
}
```

Then in the subclass function:

```cpp
LRESULT CALLBACK EditSubclassProc(HWND hWndEdit, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIDSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    LRESULT ret{};

    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CONTEXTMENU:        
    {
        HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook{ SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART, NULL,
            [](HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD Event, HWND hWnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD idEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
            {
                if (idObject == OBJID_CLIENT && idChild == CHILDID_SELF)
                {
                    HMENU hMenuContextEdit{ (HMENU)SendMessage(hWnd, MN_GETHMENU, NULL, NULL) };

                    // Do what you want to do
                }
            },
            GetCurrentProcessId(), GetCurrentThreadId(), WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT) };

        ret = DefSubclassProc(hWndEditMessage, Msg, wParam, lParam);

        UnhookWinEvent(hWinEventHook);
    }
    break;
    default:
        {
            ret = DefSubclassProc(hWndEdit, Msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Marked it as answer even if i can't try it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. How do we use this in context though? Given we have a control on our dialog mapped to a variable call `m_editControl`? Or can you link to the things you refer to? To flesh out this answer?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I've edit my answer to add details.

Comment: Thank you. For me, I think I can therefore use `m_editControl.SubclassDlgItem(IDC_EDIT, this);` for the first bit.

Comment: I suppose that your way avoids the need to derive a new class from `CEdit`? I am unfamiliar with the approach you are using here - looks more native Win32 as opposed to MFC/

Comment: in my test `CDialog` class all I can see in ClassWizard is `LRESULT CMFCApplication2Dlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` which returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found how to do it

```
static bool is_first_time;

case WM_CONTEXTMENU: {
   is_first_time = true;
   original_window_proc(message,wparam,lparam);
   break;

case WM_ENTERIDLE:
    if (wparam == MSGF_MENU) {
        if (is_first_time) {
            is_first_time = false; 
            MENUBARINFO mbi;
            memset(&mbi, 0, sizeof(MENUBARINFO));
            mbi.cbSize = sizeof(MENUBARINFO);
            GetMenuBarInfo((HWND)lparam, OBJID_CLIENT, 0, &mbi);
            if (::IsMenu((HMENU)mbi.hMenu)) {
               .... add your menu items here
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately this does not work because the code uses `TrackPopupMenu` with the `TPM_RETURNCMD` and `TPM_NONOTIFY` flags. So you can add new menu items but there is no way to handle the commands. Bad Microsoft, very bad design.